# iTunes Connect request contract for paid applications

Tags: app-store-connect

There is a problem when I try to request contract on iTunes Connect.

On page **Contracts, Tax, and Banking** I see column **Legal Entity** in which I can see my Address and Postal Code.

But when I try to request contract for paid application in next web form I get new Postal Code with another numbers.

Anybody has the same problem?

Comment: Are you the team leader of your account? (is it a personal or company account?) Are you able to take a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Hi! thanks for response. I already requested my contract. But the problem is next: before request my user account data is correct. when I click on request contract I get new form with all my user account data (but just one field is not correct - there is Postal Code field). So maybe this is some javascript issues on the site or other I don't know, but the fact that the request contract form display another my information.

Comment: Can you edit the field that the site shows you when it appears incorrect? If not, then I would definitely recommend contacting Apple by telephone for a direct response and assistance - list of numbers are here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did it. :) in response they just recommended me request contract :)

Comment: Ah excellent! Remember to post that as the answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent email to Apple where I describe my issues.  In response they just recommended me request contract.